# Why am I able to execute an $http function just by adding .success to it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I created a factory that returns an `$http` promise.

```
loginRsrc.factory('loginSrvc', ['$http', function($http){

    var http = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://myproj.herokuapp.com/api/signIn",
        data: $.param({email: "joe@gmail.com", password: "1234567"}),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });

    return http;
```

I use this factory in a controller. But I'm getting funny behaviour.

When I say

```
loginSrvc()
        .success(function(res){
            console.log("res:");
            console.log(res);
        })
        .error(function(res){
            console.log("res");
            console.log(res);
        });
```

I get an error that `TypeError: object is not a function`.

But when I say (omitting parentheses)

```
loginSrvc
        .success(function(res){
            console.log("res:");
            console.log(res);
        })
        .error(function(res){
            console.log("res");
            console.log(res);
        });
```

it works great! The success prints to the console.

I can't understand this weird behaviour. Just adding a `success` function calls the `$http` activity?

This is my full controller:

```
loginApp.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'loginSrvc', function($scope, $state, loginSrvc){

    $scope.loginForm = {};
    $scope.loginForm.email = "";
    $scope.loginForm.password = "";

    $scope.submit = function(){

        loginSrvc
        .success(function(res){
            console.log("res:");
            console.log(res);
        })
        .error(function(res){
            console.log("res");
            console.log(res);
        }); 
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your service is returning the invoked `$http` service already, so there's no need to invoke it a second time from the controller. The promise is already available.

A better pattern is to use `ngResource` such that you can abstract your handlers with their own respective promises for each API end point.

Comment: I would have used `$resource` but I was having this problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375710/how-do-you-send-x-www-form-urlencoded-data-with-angular-resource

Comment: Use the `transformRequest()` method.

Answer (score 1):

That is passing without parentheses is because `loginSrvc` is an object NOT a function.

Factory API instantiates an `Object`

Since, you were trying to invoke an Object as a function, that is why you had an error:

`TypeError: object is not a function`