# how to send x-www-form-urlencoded data using ngResource module with angular?

Tags: angularjs, rest, ngresource

everything lives in the title.

when producing a resource in angular :

```
myModule.factory('MyResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('api/MyResource/:id');

}]);
```

and using in a controller :

```
MyResource.save({att: att, att2: att2});
```

the Service sends the data in a `json` artifact ahead to the server.

I need to send the data in a `x-www-form-urlencoded` shape.

Where ought I modify my code to resolve that ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I finally found myself:

When defining a resource and the associated instruction, the "headers" parameter comes in hand.

```
myModule.factory('MyResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('api/MyResource/:id', {}, {
      save: { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }
    });

}]);
```

Comment: still data is sent as json

Comment: the parameters should be serialized

Answer (score 3):

Should pass the `headers` parameters

```
myModule.factory('MyResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/MyResource/:id', {}, {
        save: {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

then serialize your data before sending them with `$httpParamSerializer`

```
myModule.controller('appController', function ($httpParamSerializer) {
    MyResource.save($httpParamSerializer({att: att, att2: att2}));
}
```

Comment: $httpParamSerializer save my day

Answer (score 0):

Complete answer (since angular 1.4). You need to include de dependency  $httpParamSerializer

```
var res = $resource(serverUrl + 'Token', { }, {
                save: { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }
            });

            res.save({ }, $httpParamSerializer({ param1: 'sdsd', param2: 'sdsd' }), function (response) {

            }, function (error) { 

            });
```